# javascript WMI queries with firefox /chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, wmi

*goal : get the processor ID by WMI :*

ive managed to make it work in IE : by

```
var strComputer = ".";
    var SWBemlocator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
    var objWMIService = SWBemlocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, "/root/CIMV2");
    var strProcess;
    var colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Processor");

    var e = new Enumerator(colItems);
    for(; ! e.atEnd(); e.moveNext())
    {
        strProcess =  e.item().ProcessorId;
    }


    alert( strProcess)
```

[image]

However- this wont work in FF/chrome since they not support ACTIVE X.

what is the alternative in FF / chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [NPAPI](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) to write an extension for Google Chrome which allows you to execute native code on the client computer.

FireFox also allows for developers to write [plugins](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-plugins-play-audio-video-games) and [extensions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/extensions-add-features-to-firefox).

Comment: hi Darin. I can't tell far users to install an extension.....wait .... you say  write an extension ?

Comment: Yes, you should write an extension. FireFox also has its own way of writing [plugins](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-plugins-play-audio-video-games) and [extensions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/extensions-add-features-to-firefox). So you could write an extension and then invite your users to download and install this extension if they want to use the functionality that your web site provides.

Comment: Darin  , IE just asks you if you want to run the Active x. the user dont have to install nothing (nor programming by me ) , isnt there anything like it in ff ? just ask if to run the code...?

Comment: No, there isn't. Haven't you seen on the Microsoft site how they implemented the Genuine Windows verification tool for FireFox and Chrome? They ask you to download an executable and install this executable on the client machine.